# Build framework as build phase xcode

Tags: xcode, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to build the facebook-ios-sdk as part of my project build phases. 
In short, the script checks for the build folder, and if it does not exist runs scripts/build_framework.sh

When executing the build phase script I get the following error:

> Check dependencies [BEROR]CodeSign error: code signing is required for
>   product type 'Static Library' in SDK 'Simulator - iOS 6.0'

**The build works as expected when running from the terminal.**

The closest SO answer I saw was [this](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9493640/facebook-ios-sdk-how-to-build-static-library-for-xcode-4-3), but it appears to be for an older version, and the link to the tutorial provided is no longer valid.

Comment: Not answering your question directly, but cocoapods does this for you.  .. http://cocoapods.org it might be worth checking out. Not only does it support the facebook sdk, but many other tools. The SDK is packaged up as a static library project, that gets built as part of your project.

Comment: Wow, thanks! That looks really cool. I'm not sure if I'm going to add it to my current project, but its definitely something I want to check out in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XCode is setting a lot of environment variables, and these must be interfering with the script. If you knew which environment variables were the culprit, you could clear them before running your script, but there are dozens and I didn't want to spend the time figuring that out.

Instead, I decided to run the script without XCODE's environment variables. If you run the script this way, you will only get the PATH environment variable in your new shell. This seems to fix things for me:

```
env -i PATH=$PATH ./Submodules/facebook-ios-sdk/scripts/build_framework.sh
```

Comment: I just got back from holiday, and will try this out. On the surface this looks fantastic though. Thanks!